# How to make Solr synonyms work with KeywordTokenizerFactory?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a field with KeywordTokenizerFactory in both analyzers because I need to search the docs those begin with a query phrase like *"Lorem Ipsum"* so I can search like `q=myField:/Lorem Ipsum/`. The result must match the query exactly, it must start with **Lorem** and end with **Ipsum** with no words between them. At the same time I have a synonym for **Ipsum** - **Dolor**. This way when I search *"Lorem Ipsum"* I want to find documents where *myField* field contains only *"Lorem Ipsum"* or *"Lorem Dolor"*.
I can't split the phrase when indexing because in this case I won't be able to make sure to find only documents those start and end with words I need. I don't know Solr well and really stuck here.
Maybe I miss something and I can get the same result another way?

Comment: Would doing it at query time be acceptable (since you're already using regular expressions)? Otherwise you'll have to generate multiple input strings, one for each synonym you want to expand. Synonyms work on the token level, and when you're using keywordtokenizer, that will just be one single, large token.

Comment: @MatsLindh what do you mean by "doing it at query time"?

Comment: Using a query like `myField:/Lorem (Ipsum|Dolor)/` - i.e. use the regex capabilities to allow multiple words in the location instead.

Comment: @MatsLindh but I do the query from the client side and the client knows nothing about synonyms. Also there could be other synonyms as well, e.g. **Lorem** == **Sit** How should I handle this case? Making something like `myField:/(Lorem|Sit) (Ipsum|Dolor)/` can be very complicated.